# Search highlight issue

Tags: jquery, search

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="#searchfor">
<p id="all_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinci futurum.</p>
```

**CODE**

```
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
     var page = $('#all_text');
     var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
     var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
     var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
     var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
     page.html(newHtml);
});
```

Hi,
this works up to one problem. If I look for LOREM and then delete it, this will happen

**TEXT**

```
<span></span>L<span></span>o<span></span>r<span></span>e<span></span>m<span></span> ipsum
```

Here is original [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8rpY/1/). it works fine, But I want to delete all **span** if search is empty, but I do not know how to do it. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the all text into temporary variable and use it when you have search box value empty:
Here is an example of it.

```js
//here we will store the original text only first time
var originalText ="";
$('#searchfor').keyup(function(){
         var page = $('#all_text');
         //storing the original text into variable
         if(originalText ===""){
          originalText = page.text();
         }         
         var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>","").replace("</span>");
         var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
         var theRegEx = new RegExp("("+searchedText+")", "igm");    
         var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx ,"<span>$1</span>");
         page.html(newHtml);
         //replacing html if textbox has been cleared
         if($(this).val() === ''){
          page.html(originalText);
         }
    });
```

```css
#all_text span
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color:yellow;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchfor"/>
    <p id="all_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euism modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinci futurum.</p>
```